# Firefox: limit cookie lifetime

Tags: firefox, security, cookies

For the sake of security: how can I limit the lifetime of every new cookie being created in the browser?

For example, limit it to 2 hours even if the site tells browser to create cookie which expire 1 month from now on.

I'm looking for a firefox setting or extension.
Simple steps to create such extension by myself would be a great help too.

Comment: Just delete all cookies from time to time, or use Private browsing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend an extension called [Cooke Autodelete](https://github.com/Cookie-AutoDelete/Cookie-AutoDelete). You can use it to whitelist websites so you stay logged into them indefinitely, while automatically cleaning up cookies for other sites some time after you last visited them. By default, It'll keep cookies active for websites that you keep open in a tab, and will then delete them a few minutes after the last tab for that domain is closed. It also manages LocalStorage and the timing can be customized.